# Phpmyadmin 500 internal server error with big number of tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have database with lots of tables in it, when I try to navigate the tables list I ma getting a 500 error from phpmyadmin

this is the related error in the apache log

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14770] [client 94.130.127.152:20932] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PhpMyAdmin\\DatabaseInterface::dataSeek() must be of the type int, string given, called in /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages/libraries/classes/Navigation/Nodes/NodeDatabase.php on line 488 
and defined in /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php:2730

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages/libraries/classes/Navigation/Nodes/NodeDatabase.php(488): PhpMyAdmin\\DatabaseInterface->dataSeek()
#1 /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages/libraries/classes/Navigation/Nodes/NodeDatabase.php(514): PhpMyAdmin\\Navigation\\Nodes\\NodeDatabase->getTablesOrViews()
#2 /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages/libraries/classes/Navigation/Nodes/NodeDatabase.php(373): PhpMyAdmin\\Navigation\\Nodes\\NodeDatabase->getTables()
#3 /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.0.1-all-languages/libraries/classes/Navigation/NavigationTree.php(400): PhpMyAdmin\\Navigation\\Nodes\\NodeDatabase->getDa...'
```

```
centos7
php7.4
directadmin 1.6
mysql 5.7

php1_release 5.6
php1_mode mod_php

php2_release 7.4
php2_mode php-fpm
```

my php1_release is php5.6 but since phpmyadmin required php7.2+ I manually changed the handler to point to the php 7.4 fpm socket

I am guesting that some resources are low on the php size which causing this error because its working just fine in my other server ...

so what config do I need to change?

Comment: Have you read the GitHub issue about this error? https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15772

Answer (score 0):

Tanks to [@MagnusEriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson)  here is the solution :

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15772
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/6981910c8c2c2fd1aaa515c2a37459e68a3740e3

in `libraries/classes/Navigation/NavigationTree.php:129`

`$this->pos2Value[0] = (int) $_REQUEST['pos2_value'];`
just add the `cast to int`